# :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease takes too long

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have a problem with building release app with Proguard enabled. Building is stuck with executing the task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease which takes for more than 40 minutes!

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:2.6.1'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.jzxiang.pickerview:TimePickerDialog:1.0.1'
}
```

What can be the cause of this mess?

Thanks!

Comment: Happenning since Android Studio updated to v 2.2 ? If it takes longer than 2 minutes, close Android Studio, start it again and build again. If not, then problem with downloading dependencies occur.

Comment: You are right. I did it and it built really fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a lot of libraries, despiste the commentary above solved your problem, there's some tips to help work with a lot of libraries.

On your App->build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true   // add this
}

productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
        // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
        // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
        minSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happens for **proguard-rules.pro** so I hide all the rule and use this configuration on my build.gradle file and it's works for me.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My build was that long that I could not wait for it to finish, it was longer than 2 hours. It stuck on this build task and my solution was to [clean local repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

```
git clean -xfd
```

After that, I managed to build normally (in less than 5 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

I just use the Clean Project on Android Studio:
"Build > Clean Project"